# Can Kudu (git deployment tool) be used in IIS6?

Tags: iis-6, deployment

Can the recenttly opened sourced engine used on Azure for git deployment be installed on IIS 6?

https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu

The documentation mentions IIS7, but doesn't explicitly say IIS6 is incompatible.

Answer (score 0):

It's highly likely it's >= IIS7

This https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Getting-started for setting up Kudu development suggested >= IIS7

This https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Deploying-to-a-server suggests ASP.net 4.5 which is not compatible with Windows Server 2003, and from what I understand Windows Server 2008 has IIS7 by default.